# Proof of Division Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have been studying number theory from David Burton and in the proof of why r is strictly less than b, I have come across a doubt.
The text goes:
Proof. We begin by proving that the set
$$
S=\{a-x b \mid x \text { an integer; } a-x b \geq 0\}
$$
is nonempty. To do this, it suffices to exhibit a value of $x$ making $a-x b$ nonnegative. Because the integer $b \geq 1$, we have $|a| b \geq|a|$, and so
$$
a-(-|a|) b=a+|a| b \geq a+|a| \geq 0
$$
For the choice $x=-|a|$, then, $a-x b$ lies in $S$. This paves the way for an application of the Well-Ordering Principle (Chapter 1), from which we infer that the set $S$ contains a smallest integer; call it $r$. By the definition of $S$, there exists an integer $q$ satisfying
$$
r=a-q b \quad 0 \leq r
$$
We argue that $r<b$. If this were not the case, then $r \geq b$ and
$$
a-(q+1) b=(a-q b)-b=r-b \geq 0
$$
The implication is that the integer $a-(q+1) b$ has the proper form to belong to the set $S$. But $a-(q+1) b=r-b<r$, leading to a contradiction of the choice of $r$ as he smallest member of $S$. Hence, $r<b$.

But why does the similarity of form of $a-(q+1) b$ imply its belonging to the set S? We indeed proved S to be non-empty but does it mean it will contain all integers of the form $a-xb$? It will contain them only if they are strictly non-negative.

Comment: It is not the "similarity of form" which implies its belonging to $S.$ It is simply the definition of $S:$ $q+1$ is an integer and he just proved that $a-(q+1)b\ge0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh yes. Got it. Thanks. Since, r >b => a - (q+1) > 0.